# Authenticating in Vimeo with xAuth

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api

I'm trying to test authentication in vimeo using Fiddler. I compose my message to https://vimeo.com/oauth/access_token with the following headers:

```
User-Agent: Fiddler
x_auth_mode: client_auth
x_auth_username: username@domain.com
x_auth_password: myPassword?
x_auth_permission: Write
```

The message I get back is a 401 Unauthorized - Invalid consumer key - The consumer key passed was not valid.

I have a consumer key, but I don't see where in the documentation I provide it. 
I tried:

```
oauth_consumer_key: biglongkey
x_auth_consumer_key: biglongkey
```

I'm not sure what else I need to provide.

I am using the xAuth method because I am writing a windows service that will check a drop folder and upload videos a scheduled times. Usually after hours at 1AM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most cases, XAuth is not the right solution. Vimeo only provides access to XAuth on an extremely limited basis.

It looks like you might be using XAuth in an attempt to hard code a user into your app. For this very use case Vimeo provides an access token on your application page. It is much better to hard code a token than a username/password pair.

Comment: I still need the users credentials to upload to their account though right? I thought about also just creating a simple web page to get their token using oAuth and just storing it. Right now I guess I'm trying to find the simplest method. It is hard finding documentation for oAuth 1.0 in a background service scenario.

Comment: User credentials are never necessary through the API, even with uploading. Any time you might need user credentials, you actually should be using an access token. If you are uploading to multiple users accounts, you should send them through the oauth flow (http://hueniverse.com/oauth/guide/) and record their access token. If you are only uploading to one users account, you should hard code that access token.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I did end up just storing the access token. The process is a bit convoluted thought. I haven't seen a good solution for initial login for service applications. I think I will create a second application to log the user in and store the token for them.